# Fastest way to read data from MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm wondering if there is a faster method than using something like:

```
while (Reader.Read())
```

to read the results of mysql select queries.

I'm randomly pulling 10,000 rows from a database and would like to read it as quickly as possible.  Is there a way to serialize the results if we know what they are (such as using the metadata to setup a structure)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `MySQLDataAdapter.Fill` method to fill any `DataTable` object - read speed is comparable to optimal usage of read data with `Read` method (depends on your while block reading way) and main advantage is that you achieve prepared data collection which you can manage or just write to XML file.